# Disable discount if delivery date

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, shipping-methods

I added one discount method using `Shopping Cart Price Rules`. It is active for `13th June 2014 to 25th June 2014`.

But now I have to disable the price rule as per the below.

That mean

1. If the order has placed on 15th of June and Delivery falls on 28th , then there is no discount.
2. If the order has paced on 15th of June and Delivery falls before 26th, then discount is there.

How to do this with admin panel? Or am I need to do any coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to do this with manual coding.

This is not a feature in default Magento.

The price rules take effect when the order is placed and if they are in the valid date range, the price rule will be applied.

Comment: Btw it also seems weird for the customer that he does not get the discount if your delivery is delayed?!

Comment: Can you point me to the file. Which I have to implement the code